Vue app using Sass works locally, but VS Code environment reporting "PROBLEMS" in terminal
Working on an application that has been using Vue3 and Sass since its inception over a year ago.  Recently noticed that .vue component files with Sass imports and variables are reporting syntax errors.  However, I am able to npm install, build and run the app locally without issues.  All the "problems" identified in the VS Code terminal actually work correctly in the browser with the desired variables behaving as expected.
The issue is that I have 20+ problems in the IDE that are not actually problems at all, but are making it difficult to be confident about the IDE with regard to new changes.
I expect that it has to do with an extension, however...

I have used the F1 "Developer: Reload with Extensions Disabled" feature in VS Code and the problem persists.



Upgrading my version of sass from 1.63.6 to 1.77.0 (latest) did not fix the issue.



A clean install did not work fix the issue.
npm ci


<style lang="scss" scoped>

@import "@featherds/styles/themes/variables";  // fine

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  background-color: var($primary);   // syntax errors begin here at $sign.  IDE does not recognize sass variables.
}
...


Important section of package.json

...
    "@featherds/styles": "^0.12.29",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "pinia": "^2.1.4",
    "vue": "^3.4.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.1",
    "sass": "^1.77.0",
    "vite": "^5.0.12"
  }
}



This is the same for multiple projects for me and other developers DO NOT have this issue in the same code base.
I would appreciate any suggestions.

What's your IDE? What are the errors? Is your IDE configured to support the file extension? Lots of details we're lacking. Maybe give a try to an article on how to set it up properly or look for an option to disable those warnings.

VS Code is the IDE as stated in the problem and title.  Yes, Vue Official extension installed.  Learned how to load VS Code without extensions and still an issue.  I am pretty much exclusive Vue VS Code developer at the moment.  I have not seen this issue before and I am out of ideas.

Well, I decided to go nuclear.  I made a backup copy of my User Settings, in case I want to try and go back to them using this article: https://medium.com/@fdikmen/how-to-reset-vs-code-settings-64dae79e769
I then nuked my User directory in "$APPDATA%\Code.
My issue has gone away, but so have a lot of my convenient settings.  I will re-introduce these as time goes, but I have been meaning to "start over" with my settings in VS Code for some time.
